# DNS fallback in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, dns

Is there any way to setup DNS client resolution with fallback in Windows?

I found that the secondary DNS server is only used if the primary is unavailable.

What I want is that the secondary DNS is used when the primary can't resolve or return address not found.

Comment: What would be the use case of this feature? Are your multiple servers handling entirely different domains (e.g. one for `.corp` and one for everything else), or do they have different names all under the same domain?

Comment: @user1686 my provider is blocking some domains on dns level, and i have latency issues when using other dns (like google or cloudflare). So I wish to set my provider DNS as primary and google as fallback.